# Terraform - I can not create EC2 instance using SG module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-security-group, terraform-modules

Could u please let me know why I'm not able to create a EC2 using a SG module that I built?
I'm getting the following error

***Error: creating EC2 Instance: VPCIdNotSpecified: No default VPC for this user. GroupName is only supported for EC2-Classic and default VPC.
│       status code: 400, request id: e91aa79f-0d8f-44ec-84df-ba22cd3307d8***

Indeed I don't wanna use a default VPC, follow below my main code:

```
module "vpc" {
  source        = "../modules/vpc/"
  region        = var.region
  awsprofile    = var.awsprofile
  vpcname       = var.vpcname
  subnetaz1     = var.subnetaz1
  subnetaz2     = var.subnetaz2
  subnetaz3     = var.subnetaz3
  private1_cidr = var.private1_cidr
  private2_cidr = var.private2_cidr
  private3_cidr = var.private3_cidr
  public1_cidr  = var.public1_cidr
  public2_cidr  = var.public2_cidr
  public3_cidr  = var.public3_cidr
  vpc_cidr      = var.vpc_cidr
}

module "security" {
  source          = "../modules/security/"
  public_sg_name  = var.public_sg_name
  ingress_ports   = var.ingress_ports
  internet_access = var.internet_access
  vpc_id          = module.vpc.aws_vpc_id
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["099720109477"] # Canonical

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  count                       = var.instance_count
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type               = var.instance_size
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  key_name                    = var.key_name
  security_groups             = [module.security.sg_name]
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.instance_name}-1"
  }
}
```

In the "***security_groups***" I'm trying to get the output from security group module however unsucessfully.

```
output "sg_id" {
  value = aws_security_group.PublicSG.id
}

output "sg_name" {
  value = aws_security_group.PublicSG.name
}
```

Does anyone has any idea why it is not working?

Comment: What error do you get when you run plan/apply?

Comment: Hello @Jordam, the terraforn plan works fine but apply is not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `security_groups` you should be using `vpc_security_group_ids`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  count                       = var.instance_count
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type               = var.instance_size
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  key_name                    = var.key_name

  vpc_security_group_ids      = [module.security.sg_id]

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.instance_name}-1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried that way but unsucessfully

Comment: @fpsouza That's the correct way, and you can't get same error.

Comment: indeed it is not working. I don't understand why it is trying to getting default VPC.

Comment: @fpsouza You have to add [subnet_id](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#subnet_id) from your custom VPC. You haven't done that, so instance is using default VPC.

Comment: you are right.. Now the deploy has been worked sucessfully. Thanks so much